# How to work with classloader and annotations

Tags: java, kotlin, reflection, annotations, classloader

I'm trying to get an annotation from a method but I'm having some trouble. What I'm doing is loading a jar file using URLClassLoader, then I'm inspecting the annotations on methods in classes in that jar using reflection and Method.getAnnotation.
The issue I've encountered is that Method.getAnnotation will return always return null, even if the annotation is there (which we can see using Method.getAnnotations). I've tested the same procedure on the same annotation type on classes which are not loaded with the URLClassLoader and it works fine.
More in depth investigation shows that the canonical name of both instance.annotationType() and MyAnnotation.class are identical. However instance.annotationType().equals(MyAnnotation.class) returns false. The instance itself however is a proxy (com.sun.proxy).

Is there a way to get at the annotation and the fields of the annotation without a considerable amount of reflection?

```
instance.annotationType().getMethod("value").invoke(instance)
```

The above would work to get at the field, and iterating through the result of Method.getAnnotations with string comparisons on canonical names would get me the annotation but surely there is a better way?

Also for educational value, what causes this? My guess is that it's because the class of the annotation loaded by the system class loader is somehow different than the class of the annotation loaded by the URL class loader.

Comment: I agree with your guess. There exist two types of MyAnnotation. To resolve this, ensure that the annotated class and the annotation is loaded with the same class loader. Maybe it helps if your custom classloader uses the current class loader as parent.

Comment: @CoronA the custom classloader does use the current classloader as a parent. I don't know how to ensure they are loaded with the same loader, I'll need more knowledge about internals of the JVM and the lifecycle of these types of things.

Comment: Probably you get access to your custom class loader. Instead of calling `getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class)` you can call `getAnnotation(customClassLoader.load("MyAnnotation"))` (with the full class name). Make sure that MyAnnotation is not referenced before this class loading.

Comment: Tried that, was having trouble with typing. load needs a Class<T>, but I don't know of a way to get T to be MyAnnotation.

Comment: @kag0 If you show the class loader code or how it's created, someone might be able to help fix the parent delegation.  Otherwise, try using `Annotation.class.cast(customClassLoader.loadClass("MyAnnotation"))` to pacify javac.

Comment: @bkail the class loader is URLClassLoader initialized using the single parameter constructor. Also, ClassLoader.loadClass(String) returns a Class<?>. I don't think you can cast that.

Comment: The problem is because a type is actually defined by its "fully qualified class name+classloader". So the same class loaded by two different class loaders will appear to the VM as a different type.

Comment: To add to the info from @Michael - create the `URLClassLoader` with your current `ClassLoader` as parent - then the annotation found will be identical to the one that your class can see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hacky solution is as follows:

Instead of AccessibleObject.getAnnotation(Class annotationClass) use

```
private static Annotation getAnnotation(AccessibleObject object, Class annotationClass){
    for(Annotation a : object.getAnnotations()){
        if(a.annotationType().getCanonicalName().equals(annotationClass.getCanonicalName()))
            return a;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Instead of MyAnnotation.value() use

```
private static Object getAnnotationFieldWithReflection(Annotation annotation, String fieldName) throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
    return annotation.annotationType().getMethod(fieldName).invoke(annotation);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue and it was quite hard to debug. My solution to this was to use the same classloader from a class instance reference.

For example, given a Jar file you want to load the class found there, you can reference a class instance from the package and get the classloader it uses:

```kotlin
URLClassLoader
    .newInstance(arrayOf(URL("jar:file:${it.path}!/")), AGivenClass::class.java.classLoader)
```

I then could successful collect the annotations of interest.

This is an example in Kotlin, as the same issue happened there, so I hope it can be of any help for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `ClassLoader#loadClass(name, true)` is needed, which will actually load the class fully *(resolve=true)*. Note that this also initializes the class.